# PHP in_array() / array_search() odd behaviour

Tags: php, arrays, boolean

I have found some odd behaviour while I was using the PHP function `in_array()`. I have an array like this:

```
$arr = [TRUE, "some string", "something else"];
```

Now if I want to check if `"test"` is in the array it is clearly not, but `in_array()` still returns TRUE, why is that?

```
$result = in_array("test", $arr);
var_dump($result);  //Output: bool(true)
```

The same thing happens when using `array_search()`:

```
$result = array_search("test", $arr);
var_dump($result);  //Output: int(0)
```

I thought maybe that the value TRUE in the array was automatically causing the function to return TRUE for every result without checking the rest of the array, but I couldn't find any documentation that would suggest that very odd functionality.

Comment: Can you provide a more complete code example? The code you posted is not very helpful. You might have just made an assignment mistake or whatever...

Comment: The results variable is assigned the line before the checks are run. Then I added the `die(var_dump($results))` after that line to see what array it was returning.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This behaviour of the function [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) and [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) is not a bug, but instead well documented behaviour.

Both functions have a 3rd optional parameter called `$strict` which by default is FALSE:

> bool in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack **[, bool $strict = FALSE ]** )

> mixed array_search ( mixed $needle , array $haystack **[, bool $strict = false ]** )

Now what that means is that by default both functions use loosely(`==`) comparison to compare the values. So they only check if the values are the same *after* PHP type juggling and without checking the type. Because of that in your example `TRUE == "any none emtpy string"` evaluates to TRUE.

So by setting the 3rd parameter to TRUE while calling the function you say that PHP should use strict(`===`) comparison and it should check value AND type of the values while comparing.

See this as a reference: [How do the PHP equality (== double equals) and identity (=== triple equals) comparison operators differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-php-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comp)

Comment: I had a situation where my in_array was accepting almost any variable using python script posting into a php script. Very unusual but this fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

You are right, the boolean can indeed cause this. Set the `strict` flag in the [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function, this way also the *type* of the element is checked (basically the same as using `===`):

```
if (in_array("username", $results, true)) // do something
if (in_array("password", $results, true)) // do something
if (in_array("birthday", $results, true)) // do something
```