# array_search() returns 1 if $needle is 0

Tags: php, arrays

This is weird thing I found with [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php);

```
$test = array(
  1 => 'first', 
  2 => 'second'
);
```

Now if the needle to be searched comes as 0 For eg:

```
$val = 0;
$key = array_search($val, $test);
```

Now `$key` is returned as `1` (the first key).

Does anyone know how to deal with such behaviour and return `false` for this check ? Is it documented anywhere ? I've searched but not found even on SO.

Thanks!

Comment: And that's why `array_search` also has a `$strict` parameter…

Comment: Which one is well documented right here http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-search.php

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2739441/3933332 (<- @deceze This might be a better duplicate for the "Odd array_search() behaviour" questions)

Comment: didn't felt it was so straight - All I found was search a `text` inside an array, Thought there would be special handling for 0. But the answer by Styphon says it all. It was just the conversion happening. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug, but how PHP handles comparisons. As `$val` is an integer, PHP will convert your strings to integers for the comparison. Converting `'first'` to an integer will give you `0`, and so the comparison is `0 == 0`, which is obviously true. That's why it returns the first result.

Comment: Somehow the conversion didn't clicked me. Thanks :-)