# Why does php in_array return true for an unmatched string value? Is this a bug?

Tags: php

I recently fixed a bug in a program where in_array was returning true for an unmatched string value.  The string '$500' is not contained in the array. If you run this script the check will return true.

If you pass true for strict mode it will work. Is this a bug in PHP or is there something going on here that I don't understand?

```
<?php
$ZeroCheck = ["none", "zero","","0",0,"0%","$0"];

var_dump(in_array('$500', $ZeroCheck));

//returns true.. should return false.. strict works.. but why?
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP in\_array() / array\_search() odd behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2739441/1255289)

Comment: In this case, the comparison `'$500' == 0` is true because comparing a string to an integer always converts non-numeric strings to 0.

Comment: PHP is very loosely typed, but I recommend taking every opportunity possible to make it as strict as you can, including typecasting and strict equality checks

Comment: @miken32 - I like it loose and fast ...

Comment: *Hm...* that's odd @miken32 - Whenever a question is hammered, the comment flag as a duplicate should have disappeared; meta question worthy?

Comment: @JayBlanchard see my above comment ^

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner LOL I was playing around with a userscript months ago that replaces question links with SO shortlinks. I'd forgotten all about it. Probably by editing the content of the comment it mucks with that process.

Comment: @miken32 Double *"Hm"*. Yeah, well now "that" is even more bizarre and intriguing. This sounds somewhat related to [a meta question I asked this summer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/371539/1415724), could be related.

Comment: thanks guys, I fully understand now