# Is this a bug in PHP arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

Let say we have an array:

```
$array = ["Key" => true];
```

Now if we tried to search for any value in that array with `in_array` function it always returns true:

```
if( in_array('value', $array) ) echo 'Exists'; // returns exists
```

Is this behavior is expected or it's just a bug?

Comment: It's not a bug. It is due to loose comparison, which is the default mode for `in_array`.

Comment: I accidentally deleted the automated comment. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739441/php-in-array-array-search-odd-behaviour).

Comment: Yes, I saw it now, you're right.

Comment: @Tarek.hms  add third parameter which is strict comparison and then have a look.https://3v4l.org/7eM2o

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie That's very useful, thanks.

Comment: It isn't a bug, it's a feature. Being loosely typed is what allows PHP to do stuff like `if ($array) {}` when other languages require `if (Array.Size() > 0)` (just an example).